# Encoding an n-gon in f(n) real numbers

Tags: geometry, continuity

Another user asked this in a StackOverflow question, but the question since got deleted (for not being appropriate to the site, I guess). The question has stuck in my mind though.

Let $P_n$ be the set of all simple n-gons, up to reflection and rotation. For example, $P_3$ is just the set of all nondegenerate triangles, where their relative position in the plane doesn't matter.

The question is basically this: What is $f(n)$ such that there exists a function $m : \mathbb{R}_+^{f(n)} \to P_n$ such that $m$ is surjective? ($\mathbb{R}_+$ is the set of all real numbers greater than $0$.) In other words, how many real numbers do we need to "encode" the polygon unambiguously?

Of course, the answer to this question is just $f(n)=1$, since the cardinalities are the same. But the corresponding encoding is not "continuous," in some loose sense of the word; an arbitrarily small change to the input does not result in an arbitrarily small change in the polygon. So, we restrict $m$ to be "continuous." I guess more formally, you could say something $\epsilon$-$\delta$-like, like maybe

$$\forall \mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}_+^{f(n)},\,\epsilon>0,\;(\forall \mathbf{w}\in \mathbb{R}_+^{f(n)},\,\exists\delta>0, (|\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{v}|<\delta \Rightarrow |A(m(\mathbf{v}))-A(m(\mathbf{w}))|<\epsilon));$$

here $A(p)$ means the area of polygon $p$. This area method of comparing polygons isn't ideal, but I'm not sure how else to reflect an "arbitrarily small change" in a polygon.

Obviously $2n$ numbers are sufficient (just specify the vertices). $m_3$ can just be the function $m_3(s_1, s_2, s_3) = \text{Triangle with side lengths } s_1, s_2, s_3$, so $f(3)\leq 3$. In the case of $n=4$, you can specify a quadrilateral with six values: four for the side lengths, and two for the diagonals, so $f(4) \leq 6$. In both these cases, $f(n)<2n$, so this bound is clearly not as tight as it could be.

As to a lower bound... it's intuitively impossible to do a triangle in two or a quadrilateral in four, but I don't know how you'd prove it.

To be clear, this isn't a homework question or anything; I just thought it was interesting. Any insights or partial results would be really appreciated!

Comment: Given that there are continuous space-filling curves, I suspect the answer is still 1.

Comment: Oh yeah! Well, that's rather underwhelming. Maybe a better question is to ask when all of the inputs of m have to be lengths between points in the polygon.